# PTZ for Onvif IP Camera

Tags: ip-camera, onvif, python-onvif

I have an application running on Android to connect and view the IP Camera.
Now I'm trying to add PTZ support to application.

### Below are the requirements for PTZ.

1) When user drags the screen to any coordinates on the application, IP Camera should move(pan/tilt) accordingly.

2) When user zoom in/out on the particular area of the application, IP Camera should zoom that area.

### Problems I'm facing are.

1) I'm not able to map the x,y coordinates of the user action to Onvif pan/tilt vector. Because Onvif pan/tilt vector X and Y value range is -1 to 1 and I don't know how to cover overall area of IP Camera(360degree horizontal 70degree vertical)

2) How to zoom in/out particular area since Onvif zoom vector does not provide way to specify the area(X and Y coordinates to zoom).

Comment: For 1., look into the standard `maprange` equation. It maps a number from one range to another. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Map_range