# Is Onvif TranslationSpaceFov translation space required to centre camera view via conversion of x,y coords

Tags: onvif

This link poses the same question and provides a solution. I need to understand how TranslationSpaceFov relates to the solution:
[Converting x/y values from on screen click to ONVIF PTZ pan/tilt values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203938/converting-x-y-values-from-on-screen-click-to-onvif-ptz-pan-tilt-values/68622732#68622732)

1. Does my camera need to provide this translation space?
2. My camera does not provide this translation space, can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do go to center action the camera has to have this translation space and you want to add it into the PTZ configuration.
When the camera doesn't provide this space you simply cannot implement it by yourself and if so the action would be very inaccurate.